# What happens if I remove a Jenkinsfile from a repository, will this remove the whole Jenkins implementation?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

If an existing Jenkinsfile is present in a repository, will the Jenkins pipeline and entire implementation be removed if I don't modify anything manually in the Jenkins UI and only remove the Jenkinsfile from the repo?

Is it necessary to remove the pipeline and project within the UI or will removing the Jenkinsfile remove the entire Jenkins implementation?

Here is an example of the Jenkinsfile:

```
@Library('shared-library@main') _
pipeline {

    agent any

    environment {
        APP_NAME = 'my-app'
        DEPLOYMENT_CHANNEL = 'test'
        AWS_REGION = 'random-region'
        AWS_ACCOUNT_ID = '0000000'
        GIT_SHORT_COMMIT = sh(script: "git rev-parse --short HEAD", returnStdout: true).trim()
        ON_TAG = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}-${GIT_SHORT_COMMIT}".replace("/", "-")
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "make build"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Push image') {
            when {
                anyOf {
                    expression { env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' }
                }
            }

            steps {
                script {
                    withCredentials([[
                        $class: 'Blabla',
                        credentialsId: 'BLABLA',
                        accessKeyVariable: 'HELLO_1',
                        secretKeyVariable: 'HELLO_2'
                        ]]) {
                        aws.loginECR(AWS_REGION)
                        sh "make push"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Trigger deployment ') {
            when {
                anyOf {
                    expression { BRANCH_NAME == 'master' }
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    deploytok8s.call('env', "$APP_NAME", "$app_TAG")
                    slackSend(channel: "$DEPLOYMENT_CHANNEL", message: "Started deploying $APP_NAME on env")
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Trigger Kubernetes deployment to env_2 ') {
            
            when {
                beforeInput true
                expression { return BRANCH_NAME == 'master' }
            }
            steps {
                
                script {
                    try {
                        deployToEnv = input (
                        message: "Deploy to env_2?"
                        )
                        deploytok8s.call('uat', "$APP_NAME", "$app_name")                            
                        slackSend(channel: "$DEPLOYMENT_CHANNEL", message: "Started deploying $APP_NAME on env_2")
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        echo "Skipped deployment to env_2!"
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure that this question is qualified to be answered on StackOverflow, but still.

Unlike some other systems, Jenkins has no direct connection between the jobs in UI and the code these jobs are using. Moreover, the Jenkinsfile cannot even define the essential parameters of a job such as its name or SCM branch configuration - a separate tool, [Job DSL](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/), has to be used if one wants to define the jobs in code. And even if it's used, it has to be triggered separately and set up explicitly to remove the jobs automatically, but again - Jenkinsfile does not control it.

So, removing the Jenkinsfile from the repository will not make anything to the job itself (except it will now fail because it's not able to find the Jenkinsfile anymore). The job still has to be removed manually unless you have some extremely complex custom automation in place set up by your Jenkins administrators - which would be a really rare case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be great if you clarified why this answer shouldnt be answered on StackOverflow - the SO description states:

"Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share​ ​their programming ​knowledge, and build their careers."

SO has plenty of questions on CI/CD and even a specific tag for it, so yes this question is valid for SO, in my opinion. 

Thanks again!

Comment: It just might be more suitable for [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site. Personally, however, I don't feel this distinction is really beneficial.